# How to find if split() is a method for list object

Tags: list, python-2.7, split

I have 2 lists as below:

```
bob = ['Bob Smith', 42, 30000, 'software']
sue = ['Sue Jones', 45, 40000, 'hardware']
```

the statement

```
print bob[0].split()[-1]
```

gives me Smith

I wanted to get more information regarding list therefore I used 2 commands:

```
help(list)
dir(list)
```

But neither showed that split is a method or object that can be used by lists. But as you can see above I can use split() with list element.

Can someone help me in this naive question. Am I looking at wrong places?

Regards

Comment: A list element is not the same thing as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a string type, you can do this:

```
if type(bob[0]) is str:
    bob[0].split()[-1]
```

str type always have the split() method.

Comment: thanks .... so bob[0] is actually a string type and split is a method for string. Thanks to @ jwodder

Answer (score 3):

Since a method is a kind of attribute, you can use `hasattr`

```
[hasattr(item, 'split') for item in bob]
```

will give you `[True, False, False, True]`